# Which certificate is meant?

Tags: node.js, linux, debian

I tried a nodejs https request to a url from two different devices. From one of the devices it work's very well. From the other it doesn't.

```
{ Error: certificate has expired
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (_tls_wrap.js:1105:38)
at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:208:7)
at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:639:8)
at TLSWrap.ssl.onhandshakedone (_tls_wrap.js:469:38) code: 'CERT_HAS_EXPIRED' }
```

The certificate on the serverside seems to be ok.
The system is a devuan based debian 9 with node 8.11.3
Does any one have an idea what's the problem?

Comment: Since the intermitent problem is an expired certificate, check out the clock of the affected system. A wrong date will cause this in some cases.

Comment: @Alejandro I checked this already :-(